# Have we ever seen Data make use of his "multiple techniques" before First Contact?

Tags: reference, star-trek, star-trek-the-next-generation, star-trek-first-contact

At some point during Data's captivity and interrogation by the Borg Queen in [*Star Trek: First Contact*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117731/) her tries to convince him go into a more instinctual direction:

> **Borg:** Are you familiar with physical forms of pleasure?
>   **Data:** If you are referring to sexuality, I am fully functional, programmed in multiple techniques.
>   **Borg:** How long has it been since you've used them?
>   **Data:** 8 years, 7 months, 16 days, 4 minutes, 22...

Now I was surprised to hear that Data not only is programmed in "multiple techniques", but *has even used them before*. I might not be the biggest *Star Trek* expert but I think to have seen a great deal of *The Next Generation* and the addition of a romantic, let alone sexual, level to Data's character seemed like a very new development in this film, contributing to his ongoing further humanization.

But with that explicit mention of him using those techniques before, I wondered if that is actually a reference to a specific *TNG* episode where Data had some kind of romantic or sexual encounter before. So **has Data explored his own sexuality in any previous *TNG* episode that this line of dialogue in *First Contact* references** or is that just some arbitrary time period without significance?

Comment: So apparently the name of the movie is a misnomer. It should be "Star Trek: Second Contact"

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Data and Tasha Yar had a drug fueled liaison during season 1 of TNG, The Naked Now. It was never spoken of again, but referenced in Season 2 Measure of a Man.

Season 1 was 2364-2365, First Contact was 2373. Roughly 8 and a half years later. Ergo, he's taking about Natasha.

If Data wasn't incapable of being robotically precise, his keeping to the second track of how long ago it was would be creepy. Instead, it's touching.

Comment: In addition, he explored but did not consummate (based on the time reference) a romantic relationship with Jenna D'Sora in Episode 4x25: "In Theory".

Comment: @t.j.l. right what it says in the title lol.

Comment: "*If Data wasn't incapable of being robotically precise*" - but he **isn't** incapable of being robotically precise. Should that have been a single or triple negative?

Comment: Should be "If Data wasn't not un-incapable of not being robotically un-imprecise".

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner It is not impossible that your grammar is not  incorrect.

Comment: Okay, does anyone else have problems parsing that 3rd paragraph? For a moment I thought I understood what @cde meant, but then my understanding slipped away again. being robotically precise probably pertained to timestamped logs he keeps as part of normal operation. being incapable of that means not having those logs. Not being incapable of that means... having those logs again? I think that wasn't shouldn't have been a negative.

Comment: If he WAS CAPABLE of NOT being precise, it would be creepy. This is the opposite.

Comment: @cde So... he is incapable of being imprecise? Not sure that's entirely true, as he had adapted somewhat to being less precise on other occasions in order to conform to social norms.  Perhaps in this instance though he did not see the need to be imprecise...

Comment: In the series, he has learnt to drop the seconds and minutes when dealing with timescales of years.  In the films he still does it, to be more android-y for those weirdos who don't watch the series.

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner: Well, he learned to do that around his human counterparts who don't need that level of precision. The Borg are more walking computers than organic beings, so the precision isn't completely unwarranted here. But it turns out the Borg Queen isn't really interested since she's trying to seduce Data.

Comment: @Michael He is still precise inside. In order to be more socially compatible he reduces the precision of the output. He (sometimes) apply precision reduction filter right before the voice output unit altering just the signal going to it without any influence backwards. If he estimates that his rather creepy output is not creepy enough (to the Borg) or may be used as an advantage (to creep oponent during negotiation/interrogation), he turns it off and output raw data.